# При использовании Json Extractor в Jmeter возвращается значение null

Tags: json, jmeter

**JSON Extractor**

Мне необходимо вытащить рандомное значение id для дальнейшго использование в других методах.

Json:

{
"data": [

```
{
  "id": 1111,
  "type": "NEW",
  "name": "All New Files ",
},


{
  "id": 2222,
  "type": "OLD",
  "name": "Old files",
}
```

}

Я делаю следующее, но не получается:

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

В результате выполнения метода с экстрактором message: null

Так же пробовал:
$.data[1].id

Answer (score 0):

Все `id` можно "вытащить" следующим JSONPath выражением:

```
$.data.*.id
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для получения рандомного - просто укажите `0` в полюшке "Match Nr"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример выполнения теста:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более подробная информация:

- [Jayway JsonPath Examples](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)